# Why does it take longer to train my Elastic Net model with caret vs glmnet?

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, r-caret, glmnet

I am fitting an Elastic Net model to a very wide matrix. I like the pre-processing functions in `caret` but I have found that it takes about 5 times longer to train that if I just use `glmnet`. Why?

```
# Sample data.
set.seed(123)
trainX <- replicate(1000, rnorm(30))
colnames(trainX) <- paste0("var", 1:1000)
trainOutcome <- gl(2, 15)

# Train model using glmnet.
alpha_to_test <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)

system.time({
  sapply(alpha_to_test, function(a) {
    fit <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(
      x = trainX, y = as.numeric(trainOutcome),
      alpha = a,
      nfolds = nrow(trainX) # LOOCV
    )
  })
}) # 7.272s

# Train model using caret using same search space.
fit <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(trainX, y = as.numeric(trainOutcome)) 
lambda_to_test <- fit$lambda
grid <- expand.grid(alpha = alpha_to_test, lambda = lambda_to_test)

system.time({
  fit <- train(
    x = trainX, y = trainOutcome,
    method = "glmnet",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "loocv", selectionFunction = "oneSE"),
    tuneGrid = grid
  )
}) # 45.316s
```